# vlookup in google sheets for multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a google sheet where i need to populate certain columns with the values from a different tab of the same sheet.

Below is the sheet which i want to fill the marked columns automatically, say the column "Sales Total 2019" to "Sales 2019 Q4" has to be automatically filled from the next tab namely "sales Q's" . The B column(SKU) is same as "item_sku" column in the other sheet.So it has to be matched.

```
"Sales Total 2019" should be updated with "Total"column from the source matched up by the SKU and item_sku , like wise the below

"Sales 2019 Q1"  = "Q1"
"Sales 2019 Q4"  = "Q2"
"Sales 2019 Q4"  = "Q3"
"Sales 2019 Q4"  = "Q4"
```

[image]

Source Sheet - "Sale Q's"
[image]

Any suggestions on this.Since it is asymmetrical having some issues.Any help

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 How can i share it? Your gmail?

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ziEXQ9UN5GFf-X4EbzTpdYXqCJVWhYEA6l2dXTBrBjI/edit#gid=0

Comment: where do you need that formula? in which cell?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one, put in H4 cell, and clear up the range H4:L:

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(B4:B8,{Source!B2:B,Source!O2:O,Source!I2:L}, {2,3,4,5,6},false))
```

You can change B8 to last row for example:

```
=arrayformula(VLOOKUP(B4:offset(B1,max(if(A4:A="",0,row(A4:A)))-1,0),{Source!B2:B,Source!O2:O,Source!I2:L}, {2,3,4,5,6},false))
```